# F# working with IDictionaryEnumerator

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

So I'm working with HttpRuntime.cache which returns an IDictionaryEnumerator as its' enumerator, which does not seem to be compatible with List or Seq, so the only way I can find to use it is to drop down into unholy imperative code like so:

```
 member this.GetCountStartsWith keyPrefix =
            let enumerator = HttpRuntime.Cache.GetEnumerator()                 
            let mutable counter = 0
            while enumerator.MoveNext() do
                match enumerator.Key.ToString().StartsWith(keyPrefix) with
                | true -> counter <- counter + 1
                | false -> ()
            counter
```

I had the thought that I could make a helper function to dump this into a List, but there could be many thousands of elements potentially so that would be a bad idea performance wise.  Any way to work with this thing in a more idiomatic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have an `IEnumerator`, which isn't generic. However, there's two helper methods to solve that: `OfType` and `Cast`.

In practice, you want to do something like:

```
let enumerable = HttpRuntime.Cache |> Seq.cast<DictionaryEntry>
```

Now `enumerable` is a proper generic enumerable :)

Comment: @Carsten Well, look at the part that says `public sealed class Cache : IEnumerable` :) It does compile, but I haven't actually got F# setup for web development, so I couldn't check it at runtime.

Comment: #DOH ... I could have sworn that there used to be a section with interfaces on MSDN (and of course it's right there under explicite) ... sorry man

Comment: I don't think your code is exactly right but it and a now deleted answer got me on the path to the solution: `HttpRuntime.Cache 
                |> Seq.cast<IDictionaryEnumerator> `

Comment: @jackmott Yeah, I'm still very much a novice in F# - what I wrote is how the same problem is solved in C#. `Seq` is just an alias for `IEnumerable`, but I forgot that F# doesn't deal with extension methods :D Let me use the explicit call in the sample instead...

Comment: Cool, I've accepted your answer. To whoever posted the other partial solution, got downvoted, then deleted, I love you man.